# Eclipse set theme system slow down

Tags: gtk, eclipse

I'm using Arc darker theme on Elementary OS Freya and that made eclipse look horrible:

[image: eclipse looking horrible]

So I tried to run eclipse with Arc dark theme so it look good like this:

```
SWT_GTK3=1 GTK_THEME=Arc-Dark eclipse44
```

by doing that eclipse started and did looked good but caused the system to get super slow that I almost could move the courser.

[image: eclipse looking good]

I tried it many times with different themes and the problem kept happening.

So why is this problem happening and how to fix it?